# start and stop ajax auto refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

Am developing a school e-learning- forums module. Now posts are loaded in

```
<div id="posts"></div>
```

using this function:

```
var refreshcon = setInterval( function() {
      $('#postcontainer').load('new/posts.php', function() {

      });
  },5000);
```

A text box for -add new response- is inside the

```
<div id=""></div>
```

and is refreshed together with the rest of the data. But I have added a function `<input type="text" onfocus="stopcounter()"/>` [stop counter does this  clearInterval(refreshcon); and is working]. 
Now the problem is. I can't start the autorefresh again onsubmit of the form.
Jquery and I are not very good friends. Please someone show me a simple function to start and stop auto refresh at will. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these functions:-

To start:-

```
function start(){
    refreshcon = setInterval(function(){
        $('#postcontainer').load('new/posts.php', function(){  });
    }, 5000);
}
```

To Stop:-

```
function stop(){
    try{
        clearInterval(refreshcon);
    }catch(err){}
}
```